# RegEX Pattern - Two step process

Tags: java, regex

I have an input value of "+000011111.11", I essentially want to remove the + and leading zero's. Currently the way am solving this issue is:

```
inputString="+0000111111.11"
StringBuffer bufOutputString = new StringBuffer(inputString);
StringBuffer bufNewOutputString = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(bufOutputString.charAt(i)) || bufOutputString.charAt(i)=='.') {
        bufNewOutputString.append(bufOutputString.charAt(i));
    }
}
inputString=bufNewOutputString.toString();
String s = inputString.replaceFirst ("^0*", "");
System.out.println("The Super converted value is"+s);
```

So essentially am using a for loop to eliminate the "+" and then am using an RegEx to make sure the leading zero's are all gone.

Is there a better way to handle parsing of this String?? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder. There is almost never a good reason to sue StringBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String s = Double.valueOf("+000011111.11").toString();
```

Comment: Did not know Double could do this. Thank you.

Comment: If the input is "+000011111111.11" you will get back "1.111111111E7", not "11111111.11".  And if the input is big enough you'll get "Infinity".  If things like that are a problem, the regex approach of JohnB is better.

Answer (score 7):

Sure

```
String s = inputString.replaceFirst ("^\\+?0*", "");
```

replaces zero or one plus sign, as well as zero or more zeroes, by the empty string. So you probably can replace all your code by this line. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I needed. But the answer provided by @dtmilano was very simple.

Comment: +1 Even this answer was at the same level of simplicity I believe :)